# Why Foreground Detection give me inconsistent detection?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, background-subtraction

I have a problem while running this foreground detection code from this [website](https://towardsdatascience.com/background-removal-with-python-b61671d1508a)

this is my code (i did slight change, to fit the latest `opencv` version):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)


#Load CNN Model
model = load_model("VGG16withALLTRAINABLE (Currently Best Model).h5")

#Creating ROI frame for capturing hand
top_ROI = 100
btm_ROI = 300
right_ROI = 50
left_ROI = 250

#Creating Background Removal Parameters
blur_size = 5
canny_low = 25
# min_area = 0
# max_area = 0
canny_high = 150
dilate_iter = 10
erode_iter = 10
mask_color = (0.0,0.0,0.0)

#Video Capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    #flipping frame
    # frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    #Create ROI inside Frame
    roi = frame[top_ROI:btm_ROI, right_ROI:left_ROI]
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (left_ROI, top_ROI), (right_ROI,btm_ROI), (255,128,0), 3) #Visual Rectangle for ROI

    #Resizing and Reshaping to equalize model input size and shape
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, (300, 300))
    blurred_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi, (blur_size,blur_size) , 0)
    gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(blurred_roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    edge = cv2.Canny(gray_roi, canny_low, canny_high)
    edge = cv2.dilate(edge, None)
    edge = cv2.erode(edge, None)

    cntr = []
    cntr_area = []

    contours,_= cv2.findContours(edge, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    contour_info = []
    # for contour in contours:
    #     cntr.append(contour)
    #     # cntr_area.append(cv2.contourArea(contour))
    #     area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    
    # cntr = np.array(cntr)
    # cntr_area = np.array(cntr_area)
    # print(area)

    for c in contours:
        contour_info.append((c,cv2.contourArea(c), ))

    contour_info = np.array(contour_info)
    contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    max_contour = contour_info[0]

    mask = np.zeros(edge.shape)
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, max_contour[0], (255))

    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=dilate_iter)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=erode_iter)
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (blur_size, blur_size), 0)
    mask_stack = np.dstack([mask]*3)    # Create 3-channel alpha mask

    #-- Blend masked img into MASK_COLOR background --------------------------------------
    mask_stack  = mask_stack.astype('float32') / 255.0          # Use float matrices, 
    roi         = roi.astype('float32') / 255.0                 #  for easy blending

    masked = (mask_stack * roi) + ((1-mask_stack) * mask_color) # Blend
    masked = (masked * 255).astype('uint8')                     # Convert back to 8-bit 

    print(mask.shape)
    print(mask_stack.shape)

    # prediction_box = np.reshape(roi,(1,roi.shape[0],roi.shape[1],3))

    #Prediction
    # pred = model.predict(prediction_box)
    # pred_class = np.argmax(pred)

    # if pred_class == 0:
    #     pred_class = "A"
    # elif pred_class == 1:
    #     pred_class = "B"
    # elif pred_class == 2:
    #     pred_class = "C"
    # elif pred_class == 3:
    #     pred_class = "D"
    # elif pred_class == 4:
    #     pred_class = "E"
    # elif pred_class == 5:
    #     pred_class = "F"
    # elif pred_class == 6:
    #     pred_class = "G"
    # elif pred_class == 7:
    #     pred_class = "H"
    # elif pred_class == 8:
    #     pred_class = "I"
    # elif pred_class == 9:
    #     pred_class = "J"
    # elif pred_class == 10:
    #     pred_class = "K"
    # elif pred_class == 11:
    #     pred_class = "L"
    # elif pred_class == 12:
    #     pred_class = "M"
    # elif pred_class == 13:
    #     pred_class = "N"
    # elif pred_class == 14:
    #     pred_class = "O"
    # elif pred_class == 15:
    #     pred_class = "P"
    # elif pred_class == 16:
    #     pred_class = "Q"
    # elif pred_class == 17:
    #     pred_class = "R"
    # elif pred_class == 18:
    #     pred_class = "S"
    # elif pred_class == 19:
    #     pred_class = "T"
    # elif pred_class == 20:
    #     pred_class = "U"
    # elif pred_class == 21:
    #     pred_class = "V"
    # elif pred_class == 22:
    #     pred_class = "W"
    # elif pred_class == 23:
    #     pred_class = "X"
    # elif pred_class == 24:
    #     pred_class = "Y"
    # elif pred_class == 25:
    #     pred_class = "Z"
    # elif pred_class == 26:
    #     pred_class = "del"
    # elif pred_class == 27:
    #     pred_class = "nothing"
    # elif pred_class == 28:
    #     pred_class = "space"
    
    # cv2.putText(frame, pred_class ,(10, 80), cv2.FONT_ITALIC, 3, (51,255,51), 5)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("ROI", gray_roi)
    cv2.imshow("Edges", edge)

    cv2.imshow('Mask', masked)



    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**My problem is**, the output showing an inconsistent foreground detection. can someone help me what i did wrong ??

Outputs :
[input image and outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXLXQ.png) (the MASK frame is the bg removal result, but the removal is inconsistent, almost cant remove my bg perfectly)

Comment: I suggest you view your results at each step to see where it might be going wrong. Once you know that either you should be able to solve it or ask again with more information.

Comment: @WillyWijaya can you please share a sample `frame` from your video that you want to process as input image?

Comment: Hello @Bilal, i change the overall problem, now i'am facing an inconsistent bg removal, do u know what is wrong with my code, or this is just the bg problem ?